# Transitioning from other local development tools to Docker

Tags: docker

I work with around 10-12 developers all of which work on different development environments, predominantly featuring either MAMP or Nginx/php-fpm managed via brew. We would like to perform a very gradual move to Docker, trialing it for development on one of our many products before committing.

The issue we face in this scenario is how to avoid TCP port clashes whilst running MAMP, Nginx etc concurrently with Docker. Having our development environments listening on standard ports (in this scenario 80, 443 and 3306) is critical and right now we find ourselves having to turn local server environments on and off depending on the project being worked on.

By default docker maps ports to the host on 0.0.0.0, is there a way to alter this behavior allowing the various server environments to listen to the same port concurrently by using different IP addresses?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you can work around it, but I think [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/)  might be better suited to solving that particular problem.  With Vagrant you can have an individual VM which runs your application (or multiple VMs per application, and each of these can have their own address and all serve content over port 80 without conflict if desired.  The downside is that it's far more resource hungry than Docker, and I personally find Vagrant boxes a lot more cumbersome to update that docker images.

Comment: @threeve You're right about Vagrant probably making this situation easier. Ironically we held off pushing Docker use until the recent public release of Docker for Mac beta as we found Docker Machine to be a poor alternative to native Docker support (we all develop on osx). In this particular situation however Docker running in a VM would probably solve the problem, though I'm reluctant to move back as it came with its own bundle of drawbacks.

Comment: Seems like Vagrant with Docker is your best bet -- we use this for dev environments and it's been working well. What problems did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that's interested I managed to solve this issue by taking the following steps.

1.) `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up`

This enables 127.0.0.2 as an alias on the loopback interface

2.) Now we instruct the jwilder nginx reverse proxy to bind ports to a specific IP address on the host rather than 0.0.0.0

`docker run --restart unless-stopped  -p 127.0.0.2:80:80 -p 127.0.0.2:443:443 --name nginx -v ~/docker/tls:/etc/nginx/certs -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro -v ~/docker/confs:/etc/nginx/conf.d jwilder/nginx-proxy`

3.) Do the same for MySQL

`docker run --restart unless-stopped -p 127.0.0.2:3306:3306 --name mysqlserver -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:latest`

4.) Now make sure other web services i.e. brew nginx are listening on localhost in the nginx.conf/server includes

5.) Adjust hostfile accordingly

`127.0.0.1 exampleapp.org # host app
127.0.0.1 exampleapp2.org # host app
127.0.0.2 dockerapp.org # docker app
127.0.0.2 dockerapp2.org # docker app`